# numpy ndarray assignment not working for simple vector

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing a simple conditional assignment on a slice of a `numpy` array below,

```py
x = np.array([[10000, 10010,    10],[    1,     5,     3]])
idx = (x <= 100).all(axis=1)
res = np.zeros_like(x)
res[idx, :] =  (np.exp(x[idx, :]) / np.sum(np.exp(x[idx, :]), axis=1)).ravel()

In [192]: res
Out[192]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

I expect a slice, so `res[1, :]` to be assigned to the values of `array([0.01587624, 0.86681333, 0.11731043])`, but it is not.

At first I thought it was the way I was slicing the array, but what I don't understand is if I do the following assignment it works,

```py
res[idx, :] = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [8]: res
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Is there something simple I am missing, that my assignment doesn't work but the simple one does?

System info:

```py
In [4]: np.__version__
Out[4]: '1.19.2'
In [6]: sys.version
Out[6]: '3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) \n[Clang 10.0.0 ]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [58]: res.dtype
Out[58]: dtype('int64')
```

`numpy` autodetects your `x` array type as `int` and casts it to `res` in `zeros_like`.
When you assign ints to `res` it works. When you assign floats, it rounds them,  and in your case, rounds to zero.

The solution is

```
x = np.array(..., dtype=float)
```

or

```
res = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=float)
```